# Exporting Feature GeoJSON from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geojson

I'd like to do a GeoJSON dump of a PostGIS table, but I want to export features (the geometry and the properties) not just the geometry. I've been digging into the [`ST_AsGeoJSON`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) function but it looks like I can only get the coordinate information (which makes sense since it's a geometry function).

For example:

```
select st_asgeojson(the_geom) from street_centerline limit 1;
```

Returns:

```
{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-65.591776562805038,41.682190576167052],[-65.591998971284028,41.682082119060382],[-65.592001213509064,41.682081025737766],[-65.593689871787177,41.681257533373952],[-65.595415661879244,41.680415888937219],[-65.595440519465640,41.680403765889309],[-65.595603134242481,41.680324459445771]]]}
```

I'm curious if anyone knows of a simple way to get the property information as well. Has anyone written a `pgsql2geojson` script yet?

Comment: Is PostGIS able to leverage the [improvements in PostgreSQL 9.2](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#JSON_datatype)? As postgres now natively supports 9.2, is anyone aware of a similar development in PostGIS? Would be nice to do without the ogr2ogr segway.

Answer (score 32):

Just to provide info on an old question if someone encounters this:

as of PostgreSQL 9.5+

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         gid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'
  ) AS feature
  FROM (SELECT * FROM input_table) row) features;
```

[Taken from full original answer here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191446)

Comment: WHAT THE ACTUAL F... I've looked for years for a way to perform a `SELECT * EXCEPT COLUMNS (a,b)` and you had the answer all along...

Comment: omg. Justa came across this, `to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'` is **gold**

Comment: I'm having some problems with the `-` operator ("Delete key/value pair or string element from left operand"). But it's working well with the related `#-` operator. That is, I'm using: `to_jsonb(row) #- '{gid}' #- '{geom}'`

Answer (score 30):

For completeness here's an actual example with ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON out.json \
  "PG:host=localhost dbname=gis user=ubuntu password=toomanysecrets" \ 
  -sql "select way,name,amenity from planet_osm_point a where a.amenity is not null"
```

Make sure your user has read access to the `geometry_columns` table.

Specifically:

```
GRANT SELECT ON geometry_columns to ubuntu;
GRANT SELECT ON geography_columns to ubuntu;
GRANT SELECT ON spatial_ref_sys to ubuntu;
```

Comment: I'm curious about this output. I mean, since this is required to output geojson files, isn't the output have to be out.geojson and not out.json ???  I'm new to this. Thank you

Comment: Well, that's just the filename. There isn't really a standard on that - some systems expect .json (because, well, they are JSON files), other systems expect .geojson, others don't care.

Answer (score 19):

Here is an obvious solution to my own question - [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)! I'm not sure why I didn't think of it sooner.  It has both [PostGIS](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html) and [GeoJSON](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html) drivers so this should work great.