# Encoding point geometry as GeoJSON?

Tags: python, postgis, geojson

I have point geometry in PostgreSQL/PostGIS which I query as follows:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) as pointgeom 
FROM pointable.
```

I'm using Python as server side script.

I want to pass the result as GeoJSON response to overlay on Google Maps but I'm new to GeoJSON.

If this make sense, can any one shade light on the code that encode the pointgeom to GeoJSON format and handover to JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Django (GeoDjango), look at [vectorformats](https://pythonhosted.org/vectorformats/formats/Django.html), which will produce GeoJSON that you can use directly in Google Maps -- we are using this in production, on a decent sized database, millions or rows and complex polygons, and it works really well.

If you want to query Postgis directly, use `ST_AsGeoJSON` as @underdark says, but note, you need to do a bit more work to get the properties in the output (which, of course, can be very useful client side in Google Maps for selection, display, etc). I [posted about](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124413/how-to-export-thousands-of-features-from-postgis-to-a-single-geojson-file/124415#124415) exactly this recently, the essence of which is that you need to use `row_to_json` and `array_to_json` in conjunction with `ST_AsGeoJSON`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't code, use

> [`ST_AsGeoJSON` — Return the geometry as a GeoJSON element](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html).