# Help serializing a postGIS query to geojson

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I have a query which I would like to serialize to geoJSON:

```
select article_title, pub_date, city, geom 
from article, location
where article.id = location.id;
```

I can serialize the `geom` field easily enough with:

```
select st_asgeojson(geom) from location;
```

and the fields from article with:

```
select row_to_json(t) from(select article_title, pub_date from article) t;
```

The problem is I can't find a way to serialize properly to geojson from both the `article` and `location` fields. Can anyone help me with this? Let me know if you need any more details.

UPDATE!

I've got some of the way with this:

```
select row_to_json(featcoll) 
from
(select 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(feat)) as features 
from (select 'Feature' as type,
st_asgeojson(l.geom)::json as geometry, 
row_to_json((select l from (select city) as l)) 
as properties 
from location as l) 
as feat) 
as featcoll;
```

which is returning this:

```
{  
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[  
        {  
            "geometry":{  
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[  
                    -1.54907226540932,
                    54.7547462165902
                ]
            },
```

I now need to add time property from the article table so it looks something like:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "pub_date": "2013-01-22 08:42:26+01"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    7.582512743,
                    51.933292258,
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Yes see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124413/how-to-export-thousands-of-features-from-postgis-to-a-single-geojson-file/124415#124415

Comment: thanks for that. still pretty confused but i'll take a bit of time to work my way through it and see how i go.

Comment: It does take a bit of time to grok writing GeoJSON from a DB.

Comment: If it would be OK to be dependent on GDAL then using GDAL with GeoJSON driver could be a faster way.

Comment: Ah ok, i'll look into that. Actually I'm using a django/geodjango setup and was originally hoping to achieve this with querysets but found it a clumsy system. Could you elaborate a little of the GDAL approach.

Comment: You can use gdal from your own code but there is also a utility program ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. Read also this http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html and this http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html. Then you will know that what you need to do is `ogr2ogr -f geojson output.json PG:"dbname='databasename' host='addr' port='5432' user='x' password='y'" -sql "select article_title, pub_date, city, geom from article, location where article.id = location.id;`

Comment: cool, thanks, I'll have a look at implementing. @JohnBarça i've got most of the way with the raw sql but struggling to find where to put the `where` clause to join the `location` and `article` table. any suggestions. I've updated above to show the stage I'm at now.