# Create GeoJSON with CRS from Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a table of Multiline Strings and need to generate a GeoJSON with the properties turning to EPSG 4326. I made the SQL below but is not in the correct format GeoJSON.

How do I create the GeoJSON using Postgis, so I have a FeatureCollection with the CRS 4326 set.

[image]

Comment: please add an example of the rows in the table and the output that you get, preferably with an explanation of why it is not correctly formatted

Comment: it is not so simple, have a look at http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html.

Comment: Edited to show the current point where I am

Comment: Tks  @user30184! I'm exercising the example provided on the site and actually seems pretty simple!
But the error occurs type "json" does not exist I use PostGIS 2.0.6, preicso enable something ?:

Comment: I apologize, I have never done that myself. However, the json part with test query works for me `select row_to_json(foo) from
(select name from test_table limit 1) as foo;`

Comment: I have done it. It gets complicted, as going from rows to JSON collections isn't that obvious, but see this answer, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124413/how-to-export-thousands-of-features-from-postgis-to-a-single-geojson-file/124415#124415, in which I cite the original postgresonline article.

Comment: Thanks for the link! As for the error I need to update my Postgres SQL that is at version 9.1

Comment: Your geometries are already in 4326.

Comment: But you might need to add the crs into the GeoJSON, as in this example: http://help.cadcorp.com/en/7.0/sis/help/Savers_GeoJSONFeaturesDataset.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.4+, you can use the `json_build_object` and `jsonb_build_object` functions to construct JSON without subqueries, which feels more similar to how this is done outside of PostgreSQL.  For example:

```
WITH test_geoms(id, point_type, geom) AS 
(VALUES(1, 'Park', ST_MakePoint(0,0)), (2, 'School', ST_MakePoint(1,1)))

SELECT json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs',  json_build_object(
        'type',      'name', 
        'properties', json_build_object(
            'name', 'EPSG:4326')),
    'features', json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'type',       'Feature',
            'id',         id,
            'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json,
            'properties', json_build_object(
                'point_type', point_type
            )
        )
    )
)
FROM test_geoms;
```

Comment: Nice, that is a fair bit easier to read.

Comment: I added  ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform (geom,4326)),  and it worked perfectly, tks !

Answer (score 6):

You can create a feature collection by using row_to_json, selecting 'FeatureCollection' as type, and rolling up all you geometries into an array using array_to_json(array_agg(geom)) in a subquery, which creates the appropriate GeoJSON using ST_AsGeoJSON.

You can also add the EPSG:4326 as a crs attribute, at the top level of the GeoJSON. When you are creating keys and values, the trick is to realize that, for example, `Select name as type` gets converted into `type:name` and `(SELECT properties FROM (SELECT 'EPSG:4326' AS name) AS properties)` becomes `properties:{'name':EPSG:4326}` once the whole lot is wrapped up by the row_to_json function.

Replace your_table with your table name in the below.

```
SELECT row_to_json(featcoll)
  FROM 
    (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS type, 
    (SELECT crs FROM 
        (SELECT 'name' AS type, 
             (SELECT properties 
                FROM (SELECT 'EPSG:4326' AS name) AS properties)
    ) AS crs),
    array_to_json(array_agg(feats)) AS features 
         FROM (SELECT 
                'Feature' AS type, 
                ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::JSON AS geometry 
               FROM your_table) 
      AS feats
) AS featcoll;
```

or with some test data,

```
WITH test_geoms(geom) AS 
    (VALUES(ST_MakePoint(0,0)), (ST_MakePoint(1,1)))

SELECT row_to_json(featcoll)  
   FROM 
    (SELECT 'FeatureCollection' AS type, 
    (SELECT crs FROM 
      (SELECT 'name' AS type, 
         (SELECT properties 
            FROM (SELECT 'EPSG:4326' AS name) AS properties)
     ) AS crs),
   array_to_json(array_agg(feats)) AS features 
     FROM (SELECT 
            'Feature' AS type, 
            ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::JSON AS geometry 
           FROM test_geoms) 
     AS feats
 ) AS featcoll;
```

which produces:

`{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [0, 0]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [1, 1]
        }
    }]
}`