# Write GeoJSON As Feature Object in Postgis

Tags: python, postgis, geojson, geoalchemy

I'm trying to create a geofence/circle from a lat/long set and I'm close except that the GeoJSON that PostGIS creates differs in structure from the client library that our front-end uses.  Here is my python to create the geofence:

```
session = DatabaseSessionService().create_session()

METERS_IN_HALF_MILE = 805

longitude = 21.304116745663165
latitude = 38.68607570952619

geom = func.ST_Buffer(func.ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), METERS_IN_HALF_MILE)
geofence = Geofence(
    geom=geom,
    geojson=cast(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(geom), JSON),
    company_id=188,
    name='Test Fence 1'
)

session.add(geofence)
session.commit()
```

This will create a record with `geojson` set to:

```
{
   "type":"Polygon",
   "coordinates":[
      [
         [
            826.304116745663,
            38.6860757095262
         ],
      ...
      ]
   ]
}
```

However I'd like to maintain the convention set previously and have the GeoJSON written as a [Feature Object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects) like this:

```
{
   "type":"Feature",
   "properties":{

   },
   "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
         [
            [
               -92.29188859462738,
               38.913722221672636
            ],
            ...
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

I've looked into using `ogr2ogr` but I'd prefer that this be an automated process that happens on creation as opposed to being a post-creation task.

Comment: As you probably noticed ST_AsGeoJSON gives only the geometry part. This http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html may help you further.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/112057/18189

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing an `INSERT` and then `UPDATE` to use the python libs `geojson` and `shapely` to generate the geoJSON.  So my code now looks like this.

```
import geojson
from models import Geofence
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape
from sqlalchemy import func

from services.DatabaseSessionService import DatabaseSessionService

session = DatabaseSessionService().create_session()

longitude = -92.339292
latitude = 39.005994

geom = func.ST_Buffer(func.ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 0.5)

geofence = Geofence(
    geom=geom,
    company_id=188,
    name='Test Fence 1',
    alert_enter=False,
    alert_exit=False
)

session.add(geofence)
session.commit()

geometry = to_shape(geofence.geom)
geofence.geojson = geojson.Feature(geometry=geometry, properties={})
session.add(geofence)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Could [this](https://www.zimmi.cz/posts/2015/postgis-case-study-vozejkmap-open-data-part-ii/) be of any help? It describes the way to create valid GeoJSON within the PostGIS database.