# ST_ForcePolygonCCW does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I am trying to output a PostgreSQL9.6 query to geojson as in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191446/84356) answer:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         gid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'
  ) AS feature
  FROM (SELECT * FROM paris.plots LIMIT 100) row) features;
```

I get an error on geojsonlint.com that the polygons should follow teh counterclock-wise rule. 
A comment under the answer notes that polygons should be forced to be forced to be reorderd counter-clock wise with `ST_ForcePolygonCCW`. Hence I updated my code to:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         gid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_ForcePolygonCCW(geom))::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'
  ) AS feature
  FROM (SELECT * FROM paris.plots LIMIT 100) row) features;
```

I get an error:

```
Kernel error: ERROR:  function st_forcepolygonccw(geometry) does not exist
```

But the function is listed in the Postgis references. Any idea?

Comment: Most GeoJSON clients do not care if polygons are CCW of CW. The validator at geojson.io does not care either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function was introduced in PostGIS 2.4.  In earlier versions, you can achieve the same thing with `ST_Reverse(ST_ForceRHR(geom))`.

Comment: With `ST_Reverse(ST_ForceRHR(geom))`, geojsonlint.com still gives me the same error, but you are right that it doesn't really matter.