# How to export GeoJSON from PostGIS with "id" property?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

Let's say I'm exporting features from my PostGIS DB like so:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(*)::jsonb
FROM planet_osm_line
WHERE [conditions]
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to include the "id" property associated with the `way` from planet_osm_ways.
Now, I know that I can create a primary key and be done with it but I want to stick to the actual information as much as possible.

Is this too much of a hassle and I should just stick to creating a manual primary key, or is it fairly easy to do?
How can I make the connection between the two tables?
I tried to do an inner join but realized that planet_osm_ways.nodes is of type bigint[] and can't be compared to planet_osm_line.way.

Comment: See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112057/sql-query-to-have-a-complete-geojson-feature-from-postgis)

Comment: Thanks, @JohnPowell! is gid something I should create manually? it seems my DB doesn't recognize it. I'm working with postgresql 12 and postgis 3.0 
I used osm2pgsql to insert the info into the DB, if that helps in any way. Should I have included some extra config there?

Comment: Well, it's whatever field you have in your DB that you want mapped to "id", that was just example code, which happened to use gid.